# How can i detect conflict in time in vb 6.0 and ms access database in a Class scheduling system

Tags: ms-access, vb6

```
Function RoomInUse() As Boolean
    Dim room As String
    Dim day As String
    Dim tmein As Date
    Dim tmeout As Date
    Dim mond As String
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
         mond = "select * from tblsched where room Like '" & Combo2.Text & "%' and day like '" & Combo3.Text & "' and (tmein <= #" & Combo1 & "# And " & _
        "tmeout >= #" & Combo1 & "#) Or (#" & Combo1 & "#" & _
        "<= tmein And tmeout < #" & Combo8 & "#) Or (#" & _
        Combo1 & "# <= tmein And tmein < #" & Combo8 & "#)) " '"
         .Open mond, con, 3, 3

    End With
    If rs.RecordCount >= 1 Then
        RoomInUse = True
    Else
        RoomInUse = False
    End If
End Function
```

What I want is if there is already a schedule in a room for example ROOM 1 in 7:00 AM - 9:00 AM in monday .then i add new schedule in the same room then in the time 8:00 AM - 9:30 AM the same day also then.the second record will not be save because there is still session in that room (7:00-9:00) it is not over yet so i want that there must be msgbox that tells the room is still occupied.

Translation(?): Don't allow conflicts in scheduling with overlapping time.

Comment: what i want is if their is already a schedule in a room for example ROOM 1 in 7:00 AM - 9:00 AM in monday .then i add new schedule in the same room then in the time 8:00 AM - 9:30 AM the same day also then.the second record will not be save because there is still session in that room (7:00-9:00) it is not over yet so i want that there must be msgbox that tells the room is still occuped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this function to detect conflicts between two date ranges (returns true if conflicting, and false otherwise):

```
Public Function interlapDate(start1 As Date, end1 As Date, start2 As Date, end2 As Date) As Boolean
    'Credits to Martin Fowler's Range Pattern Algorithm
    interlapDate = end1 >= start2 And end2 >= start1
End Function
```

See article [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestIfDateRangesOverlap)

And to put that into perspective, you may use something like:

```
Private Function roomIsAvailable() as Boolean
    Dim strQuery as string
    Dim rs as New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim newTimeIn as Date
    Dim newTimeOut as Date

    'Initialize        
    roomIsAvailable = True

    'Assuming from ur sample code that combo1 and combo2 are the user-input range
    newTimeIn = TimeValue(CDate(combo1))
    newTimeOut = TimeValue(CDate(combo2))


    strQuery = "SELECT time_start, time_end" & _ 
               " FROM tbl_sched" & _
               " WHERE room LIKE '" & Combo2.Text & "'" & _
               " AND day LIKE '" & Combo3.Text & "'"

    rs.open strQuery, con, 3, 3

    Do While Not rs.EOF 
        'Compare new range to each range saved in database
        If interlapDate(rs!time_start, rs!time_end, newTimeIn, newTimeOut) Then 
            GoTo conflictFound
            Exit Do
        End If
        rs.moveNext 
    Loop

    Exit Function
    conflictFound:
        Msgbox "Overlap found!",vbExclamation
        roomIsAvailable = False
    End Function
```

Comment: sir what if in the problem like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805666/detecting-conflict-in-day-vb-6-0-and-ms-access

Comment: I see, so gets a bit tricky when it comes down to filtering the Day field. Of course you can just PAD your day value with WILDCARD operators (%): " AND day LIKE '%" & Combo3.Text & "'%"  ....

Comment: however, this wouldn't suffice your requirement because both  'T' and 'TH', contain a similar character ('T'). Might i suggest that you use a 3-level code for each day, i.e. M = 'Mon', T = 'Tue', TH = 'Thu', etc...MW = 'MonWed', TTh = 'TueThu'.. Please let me know if you're willing to compromise, I'd be more than glad to help you through this

Comment: Thank you again whitehat wannabe, that answers my question  :)  godbless

Comment: oops . TueThu didnt detect conflict with Tue with the same schedule ? what happen ?

Comment: oh sir .there's a problem again . if their is existing Tue then i add ThuTue with the same sched then it didnt prompt conflict ?? what happen ? but if ThuTue is existing then i add Tue it prompt conflict

Comment: as well as Mon is existing then i add MonWed with the same sched  it doesnt prompt conflict .please help me whitehat wannabe