# Detecting Conflict in Day vb 6.0 and ms access

Tags: vb6

I have these records on my Day Table name tblday

1. M
2. T
3. W
4. TH
5. F
6. S
7. MW
8. TTH
9. WF

Let say if I have this existing schedule:

- ScheduleID = 10001
- StartTime = 8:30 AM
- EndTime = 1:00 PM
- Day = M
- Room = AVR
- Course = BSN

Then If I add this new entry

- ScheduleID = 10002
- StartTime = 9:00 AM
- EndTime = 10:00 AM
- Day = MW
- Room = AVR
- Course = BSN

This should prompt a conflict in schedule because there is already a schedule for monday, then the new entry shouldn't be added. : )

Note: MW means 'Monday' AND 'Wednesday', I used this if they have both the same schedule. Because it would become redundant if add a new schedule for monday and add another for thursday with the same day, time, room and course. Also the same as TTH and MWF I can only detect conflict if it is not a combination of both Days (e.g MTH, TF, ...) I really spend a lot of time regarding this issue. Please I really need your help : (

Heres the code:

```
Function RoomInUse() As Boolean<br><br>
    Dim room As String<br>
    Dim day As String<br>
    Dim starttime As Date<br>
    Dim endtime As Date<br>
    Dim mond As String<br>
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset<br>
    With rs<br>
         mond = "select * from tblsched where room Like '" & room & "%' and day like '" & room & "' and (starttime <= #" & starttime & "# And " & _<br>
        "endtime >= #" & starttime & "#) Or (#" & starttime & "#" & _<br>
        "<= starttime And endtime < #" & endtime & "#) Or (#" & _<br>
       starttime & "# <= sarttime And starttime < #" & endtime & "#)) " '"<br>
         .Open mond, con, 3, 3<br>

    End With
    If rs.RecordCount >= 1 Then
        RoomInUse = True
    Else
        RoomInUse = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: please help me experts :(

Comment: We can't help if we don't know how you have coded it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i detect conflict in time in vb 6.0 and ms access database in a Class scheduling system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790381/how-can-i-detect-conflict-in-time-in-vb-6-0-and-ms-access-database-in-a-class-sc)

Comment: please edit your question, and add the code you posted in your other question about this issue

Comment: VBA ≠ VB, so it helps to know which you are really asking about.  MS Access uses VBA.

Comment: calling all the experts who can help me :(